# How would I be able to set a limit to what a sum could be, and if that limit is passed I would loop it too 0 and continue from there

Tags: python-3.x

I'm working on a CCC problem and I'm wondering how I would be able to set a limit to what a sum could be, and if that sum is passed, it could continue from 0. So if the limit is 2360 and we have to add 5 to 2358 the answer would be 3

I've tried using an If statement so that if the sum is larger then the limit the base number would be equal to 0. That did not work.

```
time = 2350
if time > 2360:
    time = 0
print(time+100)
```

I except the program to loop once the the number is passed 2360

Comment: Sorry about that, does that isn't the full program, it's just a demo so you understand the problem.

Comment: Even if I fix that, the problem is still prevalent.

Comment: My bad, I forgot to add something to the example code, but when I run this I get 2350+100 which is 2450 which shouldn't happen considering 2450 is over the limit of 2360. I should be getting 90.

Comment: Do you know how I would be able to see weather it larger afterwords?

Comment: I see, thank you, by chance would you know how to add the missing difference?

Comment: Never mind I got it, thank you though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to subtract time(2363) from max(2360) and make it absolute value.

(max)2360 - (time)2363 = -3

Absolute value is always positive number.

```
max = 2360
time = 2363
if time > max:
    time = abs(max - time) 
print(time+100)
```

Hope it helps.